# Наблюдатель во vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

установил watch для объекта "name" но при изменении объекта он не  срабатывает, но когда он применяется к простым типам данных работает так как и ожидалось.

Почему не работает для объектов ? и как мне установить наблюдатель за объектом ?

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input v-model="name.title">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      name: {
        title: "text",
        arr: ["12", 99]
      }
    };
  },
  watch: {
    name: (newName, oldName) => {
      console.log(oldName);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
watch: {
 name:{
  handler: function(newName, oldName){
    console.log(oldName);
  },
  deep: true
} },
```

Документация: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch